# Accessing multiple scroll bars using selenium

Tags: iframe, selenium, scrollbar

How to perform actions on the scroll bar present in an iFrame?

Issue 1:

I need to click on the link present in an iFrame which is displayed on scrolling the vertical bar. But when I try to click the link Selenium 2.0 is unable to find the element and it is scrolling the web page scroll bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be scrolling to the webElement inside the iFrame rather than trying to scroll using the scroll bar?

Comment: Hi AJ, When I mouse hover a particular element the text or the elements are not visible to the web driver and hence couldn't perform any action.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve it is making your link visible through javascript (Changing the hidden property to visible).

Anyway, did you try sending a spacebar press using sendKeys? It will scroll down if you are already on the iframe

Comment: The element I need to click will be displayed on mouse hovering. But on mouse hovering no element is visible to Selenium so I am unable to perform any action.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to click the element - without seeing it (also in iframe). When I tried scrolling, or element.click(), the iframe scrollbar broke and test was unable to continue.

If you cannot find it like this, try using js to find it aswell.

```
WebElement element = getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("element_id"))

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) getWebDriver();
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```